# Is it possible to center align text in ExtJS textfield?

Tags: css, extjs

The code

```
name: 'intIP',
fieldLabel: 'internal IP',
xtype: 'textfield',
readOnly: true,
cls: 'cTextAlign'
```

The style

```
.cTextAlign{
    text-align: right;
    background: red;
}
```

This aligns and paints red the label field instead of text inside textfield.
Is it possible to style the text in textfield?

Comment: you can also do this by adding a `fieldStyle` to your `textfield`> `fieldStyle : 'text-align: center;'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you must use `fieldCls` instead of `cls`

http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#/api/Ext.form.field.Text-property-inputEl

Comment: i wish you long and happy life! Thank you very much.